# How to add a url into html file

Tags: python, html, iframe

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the    iframe:</p>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAPi0wzs7IlNc4nlL3atU7iCd-A9QXfuHs&q=4.5596%2C-76.2801&zoom=18&maptype=satellite" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

So have this html file created on my computer, now i need to change what goes after src to a new string, example this -

> https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAPi0wzs7IlNc4nlL3atU7iCd-A9QXfuHs&q=25.5596%2C-7.2801&zoom=18&maptype=satellite

So how can i add that example line into a html file after src=?

Comment: so youre asking how to change the `src` of an `iframe` tag?

Comment: Yes, my url data changes everyday and i need to keep src updated

Comment: you will probably have to change it manually

Comment: @AlexShakhnovskiy you can use `BeautifulSoup` to get the iframe tag and change the src.

Comment: Well, i thought about that but its changes every couple hours or so, so whenever i ran the code i have to have it updated.It should be possible, but idk how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlstr = '''
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the    iframe:</p>

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAPi0wzs7IlNc4nlL3atU7iCd-A9QXfuHs&q=4.5596%2C-76.2801&zoom=18&maptype=satellite" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlstr)

iframe = soup.find('iframe')
iframe["src"] = "test"
print(soup)
```

this should be the solution you're looking for. replace the `iframe["src"] = "test"` with the link you want to provide and save the result back to the html file.

Comment: Thanks but i tried running it and im getting

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    html = open('api.htm').read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    iframe = soup.find('iframe')
    iframe["src"] = "test"
    with open("output_api.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(soup)
    print(soup)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

on line 8

Comment: I assume it didn't find the `iframe` tag and therefore the `iframe["src"] = "test"` fails. Have you stepped through your code and checked if ` soup = BeautifulSoup(html)` gives you the correct page?

Comment: @AlexShakhnovskiy does the `soup` variable really contain a `iframe` tag?

Comment: @AlexShakhnovskiy now what doesn't work. The code I posted you works perfectly for me on `python 3.7.2` I don't want to say grumpy but you'll need to make yourself clearer for me to be able to help you.

Comment: Ok, the nonetype error is still there, even know it did print soup 1 time with all the info, and then it stopped printing anything(this is where im now)

Comment: `NoneType` errors mean you try to acces something that isn't there. "and then it stopped printing anything" is not a really usefull error description.

Comment: I know, im sorry but i dont see the way to debug it other than print in the middle of the code.

Comment: @AlexShakhnovskiy use a debugger and step through the code, check the variables. VSCode with python extension for example would let you do this